# How to change datatype float to string in laravel migration

Tags: laravel, types, migration

I am trying to change datatype of one of my field from float to string but i am facing an issue

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have 
>           an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>            corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
>           near '' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE patient
>            MODIFY height varchar)

my migration:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE patient MODIFY height varchar');
}
```

How i can achieve my target:
Your help need here

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('patient', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->string('height')->change();
    });


}
```

Comment: Make sure you have doctrine/dbal installed via composer

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's change method :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('patient', function ($table) {

        $table->string('height')->change();
    });
}
```

Also your SQL syntax should be :

```
ALTER TABLE patient MODIFY height varchar(255);
```

**Update :**

As per the laravel's documentation :

> Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.

So Laravel's `change` will not work directly as you have a `float` column which laravel internally makes as `double(8,2)`. Please update your raw SQL syntax using what I have given and try again.

Comment: this should work, can you show the code you tried earlier using this method?

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your table structure. You can do `desc patient` in MySQL terminal client and post the output please? Also is it `patient` or `patients`?

Comment: I have updated my answer, Can you try removing typehint `Blueprint $table` and just use $table in up function and try again?

Comment: Make sure you have doctrine/dbal installed via composer